# PHP Session variables null after about 30 minutes

Tags: php, linux, session, variables

I'm having an issue with session variables becoming null after about 35-40 minutes. However, the session ID appears to still show as valid (and the same number as it was before).

I've created some testing code which reads and displays the session variables and then reloads the page after an increasing number of seconds. It works until it gets to 2400 seconds, at which point the variables are null on next display. In other words, it's always null when it waits 2400 seconds between refresh. I've set the session.gc_maxlifetime in .htaccess to 7800 (and it's apparently set because it reads as 7800 with ini_get).

I'm either missing something obvious or some serious strangeness is at work here. This is driving me nuts.

This is on a Linux VPS with WHM.

Code to create the test session:

```
<?php
    // start session
    session_start();

    // set session value
    $_SESSION["session_memberid"] = 1234567;
    $_SESSION["session_refresh"] = 2000;

    // write file, close
    session_write_close();

    // display confirmation
    echo json_encode(array(
        '$_SESSION["session_memberid"]' => $_SESSION["session_memberid"],
        'session_id' => session_id(),
        'maxlifetime' => ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime')
    ));
?>
```

Code to read the session (is reloaded automatically):

```
<?php
// start session
session_start();

// get session id
$session_id = session_id();

// get stored memberid
$member_id = $_SESSION['session_memberid'];
$_SESSION['session_memberid'] = $member_id;

// get last activity
$lastactivity = $_SESSION["last_activity"];

// increasing refresh time
$refresh = $_SESSION["session_refresh"];
$_SESSION["session_refresh"] = $refresh + 100;

// update time
$_SESSION["last_activity"] = time();

// write file, close
session_write_close();

...
(code to display and refresh variables)
```

Output when valid read:

```
{"memberid":1234567,"session_id":"c9d20d4992f184f29b259ef5ccab275f","sessionpath":"\/tmp","maxlifetime":"7800","sessioncookiepath":"\/","sessioncookielifetime":"0","referrer":"","autostart":"0","cache":false,"time":1365004882,"cookie":{"lifetime":0,"path":"\/","domain":"","secure":false,"httponly":false},"refresh":2400}
```

Output when invalid read shows memberid (the variable that we need), time (last_activity) and refresh time as null.

Any ideas?

Comment: One other note: I inspected the sess_ file in the /tmp directory using vi. Strangely the file was empty (though vi gave me a warning about me not having access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was that php.ini wasn't correctly being overridden by settings in .htaccess or ini_set at runtime, even though ini_get showed the value as overridden. The reason isn't clear but the working fix has been to simply change the session.gc_maxlifetime in the php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the apache user doesn't have permissions to write in the /tmp directory, and the session is only active in ram for that time period. Once expunged out of ram, it would default to the file, which never got written to because of permissions?

Comment: It now appears that the cause of this is the lack of ini_set or .htaccess setting to override the php.ini session.gc_maxlifetime setting. This setting was updated to 7800 and it now appears session variables are maintained. The empty sess_ files in vi was due to permissions not allowing them to be read/displayed. Contents were verified by logging in as root.